# Tensorflow - Making a neural network to handle simple array/list input

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow

I am attempting to make a neural network with Tensorflow, but I am having trouble figuring out how to make a network that takes simple simple numpy array/list input.  I've tried following Tensorflow tutorials, but most use the mnist handwriting dataset.

For instance, I'd like to have simple X and Y data like this.

```
X = np.array(([3, 5], [5, 1], [10, 2]), dtype=float)
Y = np.array(([75], [82], [93]), dtype=float)
```

Where X consists of hours slept and hours spent studying for an exam. 
And Y consists of the corresponding grades received on those exams.  All the network would have to consist of is 2 input nodes, 3-5 hidden nodes, and a single output node.

The example I've been trying to follow is 
https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/multilayer_perceptron.py

Answer (score -1):

> The following content is from "Geting started with Tensorflow" from Stack Overflow Documentation
>   ([archived here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170816194706/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/tensorflow/856/getting-started-with-tensorflow/4069/basic-example#t=20161125043638767812)); copyright 2017 by [Engineero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3670871/engineero), [Maciej Lipinski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7240351/maciej-lipinski), [Nicolas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4282745/nicolas), [daoliker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6719992/daoliker), [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6416660/steven), and [Mad Matts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6242846/mad-matts); licensed
>   under CC BY-SA 3.0. An archive of the full Stack Overflow
>   Documentation content can be found at archive.org, in which this
>   example is indexed by its topic ID: 856, as example: 4069.

Tensorflow is more than just a deep learning framework.  It is a general computation framework to perform general mathematical operations in a parallel and distributed manner.  An example of such is described below.

## Linear Regression

A basic statistical example that is commonly utilized and is rather simple to compute is fitting a line to a dataset. The method to do so in tensorflow is described below in code and comments.

The main steps of the (TensorFlow) script are:

1. Declare placeholders (`x_ph`, `y_ph`) and variables (`W`, `b`)
2. Define the initialization operator (`init`)
3. Declare operations on the placeholders and variables (`y_pred`, `loss`, `train_op`)
4. Create a session (`sess`)
5. Run the initialization operator (`sess.run(init)`)
6. Run some graph operations (e.g. `sess.run([train_op, loss], feed_dict={x_ph: x, y_ph: y})`)

The graph construction is done using the Python TensorFlow API (could also be done using the C++ TensorFlow API). Running the graph will call low-level C++ routines.

```py
'''
function: create a linear model which try to fit the line 
          y = x + 2 using SGD optimizer to minimize 
          root-mean-square(RMS) loss function

'''
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# number of epoch
num_epoch = 100

# training data x and label y
x = np.array([0., 1., 2., 3.], dtype=np.float32)
y = np.array([2., 3., 4., 5.], dtype=np.float32)

# convert x and y to 4x1 matrix
x = np.reshape(x, [4, 1])
y = np.reshape(y, [4, 1])

# test set(using a little trick)
x_test = x + 0.5
y_test = y + 0.5

# This part of the script builds the TensorFlow graph using the Python API

# First declare placeholders for input x and label y
# Placeholders are TensorFlow variables requiring to be explicitly fed by some 
# input data
x_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])
y_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])

# Variables (if not specified) will be learnt as the GradientDescentOptimizer
# is run
# Declare weight variable initialized using a truncated_normal law
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1, 1], stddev=0.1))
# Declare bias variable initialized to a constant 0.1
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[1]))

# Initialize variables just declared 
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

# In this part of the script, we build operators storing operations
# on the previous variables and placeholders.
# model: y = w * x + b
y_pred = x_ph * W + b

# loss function
loss = tf.mul(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.sub(y_pred, y_ph))), 1. / 2)
# create training graph
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)

# This part of the script runs the TensorFlow graph (variables and operations
# operators) just built.
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # initialize all the variables by running the initializer operator
    sess.run(init)
    for epoch in xrange(num_epoch):
        # Run sequentially the train_op and loss operators with
        # x_ph and y_ph placeholders fed by variables x and y
        _, loss_val = sess.run([train_op, loss], feed_dict={x_ph: x, y_ph: y})
        print('epoch %d: loss is %.4f' % (epoch, loss_val))

    # see what model do in the test set
    # by evaluating the y_pred operator using the x_test data
    test_val = sess.run(y_pred, feed_dict={x_ph: x_test})
    print('ground truth y is: %s' % y_test.flatten())
    print('predict y is     : %s' % test_val.flatten())
```